# The debug console show : Error: Member not found: 'DefaultTabController.maybeOf'. when i using a bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, convex-bottom-bar

This is my bottom navigation bar code with the dependencies convex_bottom_bar: ^3.2.0.
The code show below is for Bottom.dart and main.dart.
Is there any problem with my code ?

````
: Error: Member not found: 'DefaultTabController.maybeOf'.
    return widget.controller ?? DefaultTabController.maybeOf(context);
                                                     ^^^^^^^             ```
This is the BottomNavigationBar.dart
[enter image description here][2]
This is the main.dart
[enter image description here][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z69gn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/unmJE.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Glt.png

** the bottom navigation bar should be show something this [enter image description here][1]
````

Comment: it would be better if you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same error, a dartpad link may work

Answer (score 1):

change the Code on:Flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/convex_bottom_bar-3.2.0/lib/src/bar.dart:478

from :
return widget.controller ?? DefaultTabController.maybeOf(context);

to:
return widget.controller ?? DefaultTabController.of(context);